# Do Drupal and YUI play well together?

Tags: drupal, yui

We are putting together a website for a client and their IT Team have ask us if we can use Drupal and YUI together.

We have not use both products before, but we have no reason why not to use them.  We have heard good things for both, the only concern that we have is the actual integration, since drupal is a CMS and YUI is a framework.

Could you all throw a few tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a Drupal 6 site and YUI working together just fine. There's two drupal modules that handles the integration at:

```
http://drupal.org/project/yui
http://drupal.org/project/yui_editor
```

I've only used YUI for the rich-text editor, not anything else, but the editor is great. All the usual formatting, plus the image handling is very cool.

The only thing I found tricky was getting it to work with a local copy of YUI. You have the option of using hosted-YUI or local-YUI. With hosted-YUI, you simply give the URL where Yahoo is hosting it. With local-YUI, you install YUI on your server. For my site, on my company intranet, I wanted a local version so we weren't always reaching out to Yahoo. You have to specify the filepath to where your local version of YUI is located exactly right or it doesn't work. And the filepath, from memory, was a little counter-intuitive (or un-drupal). Unfortunately I can't access the site from here to remind myself of the exact problem.

In short, go for it.

Answer (score 0):

There are some modules that use YUI, for example the rich text editor. That means it's at least *possible* to use them together, though of course I don't know what issues if any the module developers ran into.

Answer (score 0):

you you can render ('theme') drupal nodes using pretty much any technology you'd like. drupal is primarily a CMS system. virtually everything is modular and replaceable. you can use drupal to power flex apps and mobile apps - not a big deal really

Answer (score 0):

A default Drupal install uses jQuery so, really, the question is more "how do JQ and YUI work together?".  Regardless of how well they interact, it would make more sense if they were to just work with jQuery and not worry about running two different JS toolkits at the same time.